Increasing section number independent of chapter
I'm using the report template on Overleaf and if I put something like
\chapter{1st chapter}

\section{first section}

\chapter{2nd chapter}

\setion{second chapter}

I'll get something like
Chapter 1
1st chapter
1.1 first section
Chapter 2
2nd Chapter
2.1 first section.
In comparison, I would like the sections to just be numbered 1 and 2 respectively (independent of where I place my chapters. Is this possible and how would I go about this?

Is it actually setion?

Just try
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
In your preamble
